# Java do while not 0 or 1

Tags: java, do-while

Ok. So I am a total beginner at Java. But why does this loop never end, even if i type in 0 or 1.

```
do {
   //Ask user to enter 1 or 0           
   System.out.print("Enter 1 or 0: ");
   upOrDown = keyboard.nextInt();

} while(upOrDown != 0 || upOrDown != 1); 
//Here the loop should exit if user entered 1 or 0, but it does not.
```

So, what am I missing here, probably very obvious and I am sorry :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do an `&&`.

You're saying "If the number either isn't 0 or isn't 1, then retry." This'll always be true, however, as it cannot be both 0 and 1 at the same time.

So, this is what you want:

```
do {
   //Ask user to enter 1 or 0           
   System.out.print("Enter 1 or 0: ");
   upOrDown = keyboard.nextInt();
} while(upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Because every number is not 1 OR is not 0.Isn't it so? )) 2 is not 1, 1 is not 0 and 0 is not 1
If you want to end the loop if upOrDown is 0 or is 1 you should use `&&`
`while(upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1);`

Comment: Wow, do I feel stupid now. I know this... I am just very tired. Logical brain failure. ^^

Comment: It's OK ;-) sometimes I'm stucking to such things too when I'm tired or had a sleepless night.

Answer (score 4):

You are basically saying **"do this until it is not 0 or not 1."** This will always be **true** since a variable can not have two values at the same time.

You should say this:
**"do this until my value is not 0 AND not 1"** so:

```
while(upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1)
```

will do what you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing to do with Java, just basic logic. `upOrDown != 0 || upOrDown != 1` is *always* true, because `upOrDown` cannot be both 0 and 1 at the same time - it's always either !=0 or !=1. You probably wanted `upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1`

Answer (score 4):

```
upOrDown != 0 || upOrDown != 1
```

Will evaluate to `true` if the number is either different than `0` or different from `1`.

Which it will be.

**Always.**

Answer (score 4):

Your condition is at fault, change it to `upOrDown == 0 || upOrDown == 1` or `upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1`

Answer (score 4):

The following:

```
upOrDown != 0 || upOrDown != 1
```

is equivalent of:

```
!(upOrDown == 0 && upOrDown == 1)
```

The fact that `upOrDown` will both be `1` and `0` will never be true, i.e. always false and hence, its negation will always be true and hence you're getting an infinite loop

It's a very famous result of Boolean Algebra (and set theory), called DeMorgan's Law [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws ]. What you should be doing is:

```
!(upOrDown == 0 || upOrDown == 1)
```

Comment: Voted up for mentioning Moore's law. It's good to learn the basics.

Answer (score 3):

`while(upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1);`

You want to exit the loop if `upOrDown` is not 0 **AND** not 1

Answer (score 3):

You have an or-condition. If one of this condition is true, it will go on. 
So if you typed in 0, than condition !=1 is true. 
See what i mean?

Answer (score 3):

```
 while(upOrDown != 0 || upOrDown != 1);
```

Since `upOrDown` cannot be both 0 and 1 at the same time, this loop will never terminate.

Answer (score 3):

do this,

```
while(upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1);
```

And you are a total beginner at Java please read this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

and

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23

Answer (score 2):

your condition is always true.that is why whie loop never ends.

you might want to change to `upOrDown != 0 && upOrDown != 1`

[learn more about while loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)